# Figma date meta check for copyright protection

Tags: copyright

Someone has probably used part of my design and posted it on a template store. Is it possible to check where parts of the file are coming from? Any metadata?

Thank you to everyone for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This question will probably be closed for being off topic for the site, but just so you do not have to keep looking: No, there is no way.

There is a possibility, but that would require going to court and analyzing both sets of history to see which is the earlier. But unless the alleged thief makes a lot of money, I doubt it will be worth it. Besides, most courts will not even accept your claim. So the best thing you can do is to contact the person and try to work things out. And if he does not do anything, maybe you can use social media. On the other hand, is it worth the effort?